# Redmine on Windows 8

Tags: windows, iis, windows-8, redmine, bug-tracking

Trying to install Redmine on Windows 8 [on this tutorial](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/installing-redmine-on-windows-in-production/). Getting this errors:

[image]

Tried [Bitnami's installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) too, but I already have IIS Web Server and don't need the bundled Apache webserver. The installer doesn't give me to choose it's components. It installs Apache by default. So, Bitnami's Redmine is not for me.

What am I missing?

Is there any other good bug & request tracking software? Please don't Google and advise me to some random results. Advise something that you used and really good as Redmine

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  Maybe try to find a redmine forum or something?

Comment: Do you have IIS Express (<> IIS)?  The installer seems to want it.  You could also check the Web PI logs in %APPDATA$\local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs, but ultimately I think the Redmine people are who you need to reach out to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you get the error above, make sure that new WebSite's AppPool has write access to site's folder on the harddrive to complete the install process.
2. Then open the website in a browser and the installation will complete.
3. Set security accordingly after the install completes.

Answer (score -1):

Use [WebIssues](http://webissues.mimec.org/) multi-platform bug & request tracking software that fits all your needs instead of Redmine.

WebIssues is an open source, multi-platform system for issue tracking and team collaboration. It can be used to store, share and track issues with various attributes, comments and file attachments. It is easy to install and use but has many capabilities and is highly customizable.

**Main features:**

1. The Desktop Client application can run natively on Windows, Linux
   and OS X
2. The Web Client can be used to access the system using a web browser
3. The server can be installed on any host with PHP 5.2 or newer and
   MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQL Server
4. Issues can be filtered using public and personal views with
   configurable filtering criteria
5. Email notifications can be sent and the Desktop CLient can
   periodically check for new and modified issues meeting various
   criteria
6. Various reports can be printed directly from the Desktop Client or
   exported as HTML and PDF documents